# Ошибки в разметке html. как исправить?

Tags: html5, теги, атрибуты

исправленный код, но картинки стали теперь в пол экрана((( что делать?
на сайте со старым кодом это должно выглядеть вот так: [astrovok.esy.es](http://astrovok.esy.es)
а сейчас вот что:

`[image: validator]эта ссылка из [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=streamer&s=A6qswNRzZaO2Ezz8), там показаны ошибки. А в этом редакторе + файл css [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cuyinaqaji/edit?html), там есть фишка в подсветках на фоне картинки. Валидатор выдаёт ошибки по закрытию тегов. Но если закрыть их там, где они должны быть, то страница становиться нечитабельной, и меню не работает.

```css
:after,
:before,
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.block-middle {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.block-middle:after,
.block-middle:before {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.block-middle:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    left: -15%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -ms-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
.block-middle:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    right: -15%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
    z-index: 10;
}
.block-middle .img-block {
    width: 33.33%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.block-middle .img-block img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">

  <title>home page</title>




  <style>
    body {
      background: url(fons/Z3.jpg);
      /* Цвет фона и путь к файлу */
      color: #050505;
      /* Цвет текста */
      no-repeat;
      -moz-background-size: 100%;
      /* Firefox 3.6+ */
      -webkit-background-size: 100%;
      /* Safari 3.1+ и Chrome 4.0+ */
      -o-background-size: 100%;
      /* Opera 9.6+ */
      background-size: 100%;
    }
    /* Современные браузеры */
    
    a.button7 {
      font-weight: 700;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
      border-radius: 3px;
      background: rgb(64, 199, 129);
      box-shadow: 0 -3px rgb(53, 167, 110) inset;
      transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    a.button7:hover {
      background: rgb(53, 167, 110);
    }
    
    a.button7:active {
      background: rgb(33, 147, 90);
      box-shadow: 0 3px rgb(33, 147, 90) inset;
    }
    
    a.button9 {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      color: #777674;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 1px 1px, rgba(100, 100, 100, .3) 3px 7px 3px;
      user-select: none;
      padding: 1em 2em;
      outline: none;
      border-radius: 3px / 100%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .0) 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .8), rgba(255, 255, 255, .0) 70%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(125, 125, 125, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(125, 125, 125, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(125, 125, 125, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(125, 125, 125, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(223, 190, 170, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(223, 190, 170, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(223, 190, 170, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(223, 190, 170, .5));
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 200% 100%, auto, 100% 2px, 100% 2px, 100% 1px, 100% 1px;
      background-position: 200% 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 4px, 0 calc(100% - 4px);
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 3px 10px 10px -10px;
    }
    
    a.button9:hover {
      transition: .5s linear;
      background-position: -200% 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 4px, 0 calc(100% - 4px);
    }
    
    a.button9:active {
      top: 1px;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0px;padding:6px; width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="block-middle">
          <p class="img-block">




            <p class="block-middle">
              <p class="img-block">
                <img src="fons/4.bmp">
              </p>
              <p class="img-block">
                <img src="fons/4.bmp">
              </p>
              <p class="img-block">
                <img src="fons/4.bmp">
              </p>

      </td>
    </tr>




    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"> <font color="red" size="+3">
            <b>Ast</b>

</font></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="index.html" class="button9">Главная страница </a>
        <a href="calendar moon.html" class="button9"> Лунный календарь </a>
        <a href="profailer.html" class="button9">Профессия по натальной карте </a>
        <a href="kid.html" class="button9">Гороскоп ребёнка </a>
        <a href="sinastriya.html" class="button9">Синастрия (совместимость) </a>
        <a href="http://astrovok.iforum.name/pages/astrologiya_onlain" class="button9">Астрология онлайн </a>
        <a href="http://astrovok.iforum.name" class="button9">Форум </a>
        <a href="call.html" class="button9">Обратная связь </a>
        <a href="http://astrovok.iforum.name/pages/programma_antaresweb" class="button9">Антарес </a>
        <a href="http://astrovok.iforum.name/pages/konverter_vremeni" class="button9">Конвертр времени </a>
        <a href="http://astrovok.iforum.name/pages/gadanie_po_knige_peremen" class="button9">Гадание по книге перемен </a>
        <a href="http://astrovok.iforum.name/pages/tolkovanie_snovidenii" class="button9">Толкование сновидений онлайн </a>
        <a href="karta.html" class="button9">Карта (пример) </a>
        <a href="moon.html" class="button9">Все о Вашей луне (пример)</a>
        <a href="karm.html" class="button9">Кармический гороскоп (пример) </a>
        <a href="pow.html" class="button9">Сила планет</a>
        <a href="fd.html" class="button9">Формула души</a>
        <a href="cards.html" class="button9">Карты Любви Р.Кемпа</a>
        <a href="/public_html/China/index.html" class="button9">Китайский гороскоп</a>

        <a href="cards.html" class="button9">Карта сайта</a>

      </td>
    </tr>





    <tr>
      <td style="width: 650px;" valign="top">
        <!-- google_ad_section_start -->
        <!--      <p align="center"><img src=".jpg"></p> -->
        <h3 align="center" style="color:white">home page</h3>

        <h3 align="center" style="color:white">tehhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
       xt</h3>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 62px;" align="right" text="center" valign="top">

        <script src="http://astro-app.net/apps-acl.js?RU132833ddffdd0033990022ee0014" id="acalendar"></script>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <!-- google_ad_section_end -->


    <tr>
      <td>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://zornet.ru/ZORNET-RU/jquery.min_raketa.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://zornet.ru/ZORNET-RU/MrScrollUp_raketa.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://zornet.ru/ZORNET-RU/MrScrollUp_raketa.css" />
        <div id="MrScrollUp" style="display:none;">
          <div class="MrScrollUp1"></div>
          <div class="MrScrollUp2"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 712px;" colspan="2" align="center">

        <p>
          При копировании материалов данного сайта, прямая ссылка на сайт обязательна
          <br /> © 2017
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: сейчас ошибки исправлены, но вид страницы стал ужасный..(( появились огромные картинки шапки, когда на сайте они выглядят вот так. http://astrovok.esy.es/

Answer (score 0):

Первая ошибка - charset=windows-1251. Установите utf-8
Вторая - слеш в закрывающем `</head>`
Третья - открывающих div больше чем закрывающих (перепутали `</div> и <body>`)

Comment: charset пробовал менять на utf-8, валидатор выдавал, что нужно менять на win1251 видимо из-за того, что кнопки сделаны в win1251 . по поводу слеш- не совсем понял. а по поводу div - если закрыть все открывающие теги- то вид сайта ломается весь. тут может быть валидатор ругается на то, что  применяются элементы div внутри элемента td?

Comment: блок head закройте правильно - </head>; в таблице у вас тег <body> которому там вааще делать нечего; открывающих <div> в вашей структуре больше чем закрывающих </div> на один

Comment: сейчас код выглядит по другому без ошибок http://plnkr.co/edit/?s=A6qswNRzZaO2Ezz8&p=linter но проблема в том, что в браузере теперь картинки занимают пол экрана(((

Comment: задавайте img{width:100%;height:auto}, тогда картинки будут по ширине родителя.

Comment: так там так с задано сейчас   table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0px;padding:6px; width:100%                                                                а вот со старым кодо все работает как надо...но там ошибки валидатора   ![ HTML](http://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image1253957.jpg).

Comment: 100% тегам img.

Comment: но они так и прописаны сейчас вот изменённый код  ![ HTML](.http://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image1253967.jpg)